# SQL, two tables, one shared primary key

Tags: sql, shared-primary-key

I want to have two tables so I can move old records into a second table so I keep the main table small but still want to be able to link to both tables using the one int Primary Key.

eg:
(I have simplified this example, from what is in my real tables) I am keeping trace of sessions and want to move expired sessions into an Expired_Sessions table but I am also linking sessions to log tables like a Login_Attempts table and I don't want to break the links to those tables.

```
Sessions
--------------------
PKey       | int
Session_ID | varchar


Expired_Sessions
--------------------
PKey       | int
Session_ID | varchar

Login_Attempts
--------------------
Session_FKey | int
Count        | int
```

I did think of two ways to do this that would work but I thought there should be a better way to do this?

One: storing a primary key counter in my sys_constants table and incrementing it every time I add a record.
or

Two: adding another table that links the Sessions table primary key and the Expired sessions primary key to a third primary key and then using the third primary key to link to my log tables.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using table partitioning? I don't know enough about you requirements but it might be worth investigating.

> When tables and indexes become very large, partitioning can help by
>   partitioning the data into smaller, more manageable sections. This
>   paper focuses on horizontal partitioning, in which large groups of
>   rows will be stored in multiple separate partitions. The definition of
>   the partitioned set is customized, defined, and managed by your needs.
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2005 allows you to partition your tables based on
>   specific data usage patterns using defined ranges or lists. SQL Server
>   2005 also offers numerous options for the long-term management of
>   partitioned tables and indexes by the addition of features designed
>   around the new table and index structure.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep separate primary keys for each table, but add another column that serves as a unique identifier for the sessions, whichever table it is in? I see you have the Session_ID... if you index it, you can even use that for lookups.